# How to Preserve Antique Framed Photos

Tags: uv, glass, print-preservation

I have antique framed photos under glass which I must UV protect WITHOUT re-framing (the solid backing on the frames contain antique documentation which must be preserved). Do you know of any clear film product with UV protection which can be applied/adhered to the front/outside of the existing glass?

Comment: Can you not just replace the glass in the frame with museum UV blocking glass. I buy it in bulk and cut my own sizes.

Comment: ...or add a thin "museum glass" sheet on top of the existing glass?

Answer (score 3):

UV blocking window films are available at auto window tinting shops. That being said, harmful UV rays are stopped by ordinary glass. That being said, silver based black and white prints are unlikely to be harmed by UV rays as the image is composed of metallic silver.

Comment: Then what causes B&W photos framed behind glass to fade when exposed to even dispersed sunlight, such as hanging on a wall in a room with a window?

Comment: @Michael Clark -- Obviously you believe vintage silver-gelatin photographic prints fade due to the action of UV light. I believe UV will only minimally be a factor. The major cause of fading of silver-gelatin prints is likely chemical. Silver-gelatin likely fades because of improper fixing and washing or the action of sulfur contamination. However, I have been wrong more than 1000 times. Just more of my gobbledygook!